# Kendo Button single click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is there a Single Click button feature in Kendo Button widget like shown below in the example link (I know its WebControl for webforms app). I am looking for similar kind of functionality in Kendo MVC Wrapper/Core. Can someone please share the configuration settings either in Kendo MVC Wrapper or Kendo Core.

Example of Single Click in Telerik RadButton
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/button/examples/singleclick/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve that functionality using jQuery, like this:

```
$("#myButton").one("click", function() {
  'Code to run when the button is clicked.
});
```

You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/).